# Remove the notification icon from the status bar

Tags: service, icons, notificationmanager

I have used this FLAG for my service : Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE; but when I call notificationManager.cancel(IDN) the icon is always visual into the status bar.....if I change FLAG on Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL when I call notificationManager.cancel(IDN) the icon is gone. How can I do for to use FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE and then cancel the icon ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question, but you can cancel all the notification from your App using:

```
final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

`public final void startForeground (int id, Notification notification)`

and the notification could be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

please refer [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24581), for foreground service

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if this notification represents a currently running service. This will normally be set for you by startForeground(int, Notification)."

To help other people who might struggle with this, it would really help if the documentation for FLAG_FOREGORUND_SERVICE more strongly indicated that users of this flag can't use nm.cancel() and need to use the startForeground/stopForeground pair. Perhaps something like:

"Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field to indicate foreground status of a currently running service. You should not use this flag directly, but let startForeground() set it for you, and use stopForeground(true) to remove it."